# How to use componentdidmount in modal only when i use modal?

Tags: reactjs

How to use componentdidmount in modal only when i use modal?
If i didnt call the modal dont use component didmount in modal?

```
{showVacationRequestModal ?
                                <ModalVacationsRequestDetails
                                    open={showVacationRequestModal}
                                    onClose={this.hideVacationRequestModal}
                                    title={selectedVacationRequest.topic}
                                    selectedVacationRequest={selectedVacationRequest}
                                    width="md"/> : null}
componentDidMount() {
    ApiEmployees.getOrganizations(Global.getCurrentUser().employeeCode).then(items => {
        let orgs = items.map(it => {
            return {value: it.id, label: it.name};
        });
        this.setState({organizations: orgs, selectedOrganization: orgs[0].value});
        this.getEmployeeByCodeAndOrganization(items[0].id);
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the entire code of the component? looks like you are using `componentDidMount` in the wrong place but would need to see the whole component to be sure.

Comment: Can't you move `componentDidMount` into `ModalVacationsRequestDetails`

Comment: my componentDidMount  in ModalVacationsRequestDetails but anyway it send request when i go on page, before i call modal

Answer (score 0):

Create Modal Component

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ModalComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        //... didmount code
    }

    render () {
        const {open, onClose, title, selectedVacationRequest} = this.props;
        return (
            <ModalVacationsRequestDetails
            open={open}
            onClose={onClose}
            title={title}
            selectedVacationRequest={selectedVacationRequest}
            width="md"/>
        )
    }
}
```

And use at root

```
render() {
        return (
                //... your code
                {showVacationRequestModal && <ModalComponent
                    open={...}
                    onClose={...}
                    title={...}
                    selectedVacationRequest={...}
                />}
                //... your code
        )
    }
```

Comment: Putting a flag before modal shows the modal only when the data is set, This directly hits the aesthetics, the modal shows up & vanishes instantly because of the flag.